# Is this a correct approach to rename a protected branch in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I currently have two protected branches in my GitLab repo, but want to rename **master** to **prod**.

[image: gitlab protected branches]

From my research I found some steps and wanted to make sure they were correct:

```
# Unprotect branch

# Switch to old local branch
git checkout master

# Create and switch to new local branch
git checkout -b main

# Delete old remote branch
git push --delete origin master

# Delete old local branch
git branch -D master

# Push new local branch to remote and set upstream branch
git push --set-upstream origin main

# Reprotect branch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your steps look correct. Note that you can just create a new branch rather than "rename" master. You can do this entirely in the GitLab UI. The steps are roughly something like this:

1. Create `prod` branch based on `master`.
2. Set `prod` as a protected branch and configure rules similar to your current `master`.
3. Unprotect `master`
4. Delete `master`.

Comment: Oh. I didn't even think about using the GitLab UI. That's a good idea.

Comment: @ldesigns Notice that my verbal description more or less is exactly what you show with git commands.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can create `prod` before unprotecting and deleting `master`, but yes, the steps you describe will work.